# How do you structure a database for a wiki site?

Tags: wiki

What's does the table look like- is there only one? How do you revert to older versions? Similar to how Stack overflow works.

Comment: Install MediaWiki and take a look yourself?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to go about this is to look at other software such as MediaWiki and see how they structure their database. Then you can pick and choose what you want to use to start off on your own wiki design.

On the other hand, you could always start off with a pretty basic spread of tables that would keep track of Users, Articles, Revisions on an Article, etc. and start spiraling out from there.

Answer (score 3):

[Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout) details in their help pages how they layout their database.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with CookieOfFortune's comment that you should take a look at an existing open source wiki to see how they do it, but I'll also offer this thought prefixed with the fact that I have no experience writing wiki software. Maybe some sort of partial [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) could be useful in maintaining the previous versions.